# How to enable syntax highlighting in R Shiny app with htmlOutput

Tags: javascript, html, shiny, syntax-highlighting

I have a Shiny app that generates computer code dynamically based on user inputs and presents it to the user so they can see exactly what query is being sent to a database.  I have prism syntax highlighting working for code that is directly in the user interface function, so I know that prism is working; but for code that is generated in the server and sent to the user via `renderText` and `htmlOutput` the highlighting doesn't work.

Here is an image of a simple example:

[image]

Which was made with this R file (and prism.css and prism.js in the `www` folder of the Shiny app)

```
   ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "prism.css")
  ),
  tags$body(
    tags$script(src="prism.js")
  ),
  HTML("<pre><code class='language-sql'>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2
       -- this chunk should be syntax highlighted and it is
       </code></pre>"),

  HTML("<pre>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2
       -- this chunk should not be syntax highlighted
       </code></pre>"),

  htmlOutput("sql")
)
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  txt <- "<pre><code class='language-sql'>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2
       -- this chunk should be syntax highlighted but isn't for some reason,
       -- presumably connected to it getting to the UI via renderText and htmlOutput
       </code></pre>"

  output$sql <- renderText(txt)
}
```

In the DOM Explorer I can see that in the webpage generated by Shiny, the third (not working) chunk is within a `<div class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output">`, then is correctly wrapped in `<pre>` and `<code class="language-sql">` tags like the first chunk.  So being wrapped in that div is what is stopping prism.js from doing its highlighting thing.

What should I do to have the third chunk highlighted like the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prism.js runs as soon as its loaded, so any code blocks dynamically added afterward won't get highlighted. One option would be to load `prism.js` dynamically in the server function as well.

```
output$sql <- renderUI({
  tagList(
    tags$script(src = "prism.js"),
    HTML(txt)
  )
})
```

But this is not very robust. You could easily load multiple copies of the script. And if you make it a `shiny::singleton` or use `htmltools::htmlDependency` to only load the script once, you could easily find yourself back in the original situation.

A better solution - Prism provides an API that lets you programmatically highlight code blocks: http://prismjs.com/extending.html#api

How about running `Prism.highlightAll()` after rendering any code block?

```
library(shiny)

prismCodeBlock <- function(code) {
  tagList(
    HTML(code),
    tags$script("Prism.highlightAll()")
  )
}

prismDependencies <- tags$head(
  tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/prism.min.js"),
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",
            href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/themes/prism.min.css")
)

prismSqlDependency <- tags$head(
  tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/components/prism-sql.min.js")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  prismDependencies,
  prismSqlDependency,

  HTML("<pre><code class='language-sql'>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2
       -- this chunk should be syntax highlighted and it is
       </code></pre>"),

  HTML("<pre>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2
       -- this chunk should not be syntax highlighted
       </code></pre>"),

  htmlOutput("sql")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  txt <- "<pre><code class='language-sql'>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2
  -- this chunk should be syntax highlighted but isn't for some reason,
  -- presumably connected to it getting to the UI via renderText and htmlOutput
  </code></pre>"

  output$sql <- renderUI({
    prismCodeBlock(txt)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

For further improvement, you could use `Prism.highlightElement()` to be more efficient. Could also create an HTML widget out of these Prism code blocks to abstract away the messy details.