# How to highlight R or Python code in markdown chunk embedded in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to return a dynamic code chunk in R as part of a shiny app. A simple example of what I am trying to do is,

````
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    sliderInput("mu", "Mean", min=-30, max=30, value=0, step=0.2),
    uiOutput('chunk')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$chunk <- renderUI({ 
       HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(text=paste0("```{r}",
                                     "\n dnorm(0, ", input$mu,", 2)"), 
                                     options=c("highlight_code"))) })
    }
))
````

This produces an unformatted code chunk. I would like to be able to use pygments/another-solution to highlight this code, and also python/other-language code which will form part of a web app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Additional Languages

Here's a solution that works for highlighting many different languages. It's based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47445785/8099834) answer, which uses [Prism](https://prismjs.com). We load the Prism dependencies and then load dependencies for each language we want to highlight.

```
## from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47445785/8099834
## get prism dependencies 
prismDependencies <- tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/prism.min.js"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",
              href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/themes/prism.min.css")
)
prismLanguageDependencies <- function(languages) {
    lapply(languages, function(x) {
        tags$head(
            tags$script(
                src = paste0("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/components/prism-",
                             x, ".min.js")
            )
        )
    })
}

## format code with tags and language
prismAddTags <- function(code, language = "r") {
    paste0("<pre><code class = 'language-", language, "'>",
           code, 
           "</code></pre>")
}
prismCodeBlock <- function(code, language = "r") {
    tagList(
        HTML(prismAddTags(code, language = language)),
        tags$script("Prism.highlightAll()")
    )
}

## run app
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
        prismDependencies,
        prismLanguageDependencies(c("sql", "r", "python")),
        sliderInput("mu", "Mean", min=-30, max=30, value=0, step=0.2),
        uiOutput('r_chunk'),
        uiOutput('python_chunk'),
        uiOutput('sql_chunk')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$r_chunk <- renderUI({ 
            prismCodeBlock(
                code = paste0("# this is R code\ndnorm(0, ", input$mu,", 2)"),
                language = "r"
                )
        })
        output$python_chunk <- renderUI({
            prismCodeBlock(
                    code = '# this is python code
# Say hello, world.
print ("Hello, world!")',
                    language = "python"
            )
        })
        output$sql_chunk <- renderUI({
            prismCodeBlock(
                code = "-- this is SQL code
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=2",
                language = "sql"
            )
        })
    }
))
```

[image: prism_shiny_app_example]

#### Updated Answer

As pointed out in the comments, the original answer doesn't work. Turns out getting the highlighting to work takes a little more effort.

Fortunately, someone has already figured it out! They have written two functions: `renderCode` for the `server` and `outputCode` for the `ui` which seem to work well. The package is [here](https://github.com/statistikat/codeModules) and the relevant functions are [here](https://github.com/statistikat/codeModules/blob/master/R/renderCode.R).

Here's an example:

```
## install the package
library(devtools)
install_github("statistikat/codeModules")

## run the app
library(codeModules)
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
        sliderInput("mu", "Mean", min=-30, max=30, value=0, step=0.2),
        codeOutput('chunk')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$chunk <- renderCode({ 
            paste0("dnorm(0, ", input$mu,", 2)")
        })
    }
))
```

[image: sample_highlighting]

#### Original Answer -- Doesn't work

`highlight.js` will format your code and is included in `shiny`. Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41792350/8099834), it supports 169 languages at this time.

You just need to tag your code. Try something like this:

```
library(shiny)
highlightCode <- function(code) {
    HTML(
        paste0("<pre><code class='html'>",
               code,
               "</code></pre>")
        )
}
runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
        sliderInput("mu", "Mean", min=-30, max=30, value=0, step=0.2),
        uiOutput('chunk')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$chunk <- renderUI({ 
            highlightCode(paste0("dnorm(0, ", input$mu,", 2)"))
        })
    }
))
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't appear to work for me, however. The code just appears unhighlighted. This is the case if I change the code to class='r' or class='R' (since the code is written in R) or if I change the R code to be 'return(c(1,2,3))', for example.

Comment: @ben18785 sorry about that! I was wrong. I've updated with a working answer. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking for a more general answer than just supporting R syntax highlighting as am coding in multiple languages. Will bear this in mind though.

Comment: @ben18785 ah yeah, sorry -- missed that part of the question. Hopefully the new answer will work better for you!

Comment: That's really great. Thank you very much. This has been a pain for a while for me! If I could upvote your answer another time, I would! Best, Ben

Comment: @ben18785 you're welcome! I'm glad it works for you. Good luck on your project!