# R Shiny syntax highlighting in textInput

Tags: r, shiny, syntax-highlighting

I'm wondering if there is a solution, analogous to the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445260/how-to-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-r-shiny-app-with-htmloutput), to perform realtime syntaxt highlighting within a textInput object in R shiny?

Comment: you should take a look at the [shinyAce](https://trestletech.github.io/shinyAce/) package. It allows to display R code with several styles

Comment: This is brilliant thanks! I'll try installing it on the server(s) here.

Comment: Be careful with the risks of this package, they are described at the bottom of the page in the link I provided

Comment: Ofcourse! I am going to use this one for highlighting SQL-syntax within the app. No R code will be executed. That would cause some serious risks. But thanks for the notification anyway, useful to be aware of the risks.